# jquery multiply audio button stop siblings playing ++ play another audio directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have multiple audio buttons. I'd like to pause all other when i click on one of them. thats working fine, but additionally i would like to pause the current one and start another directly.

```js
var playing = false;

jQuery('.player').click(function() {
  jQuery('.player').removeClass('playing');
    jQuery(this).addClass('playing');

    jQuery('.playing').each(function(){
      var audio = jQuery(this).find('audio')[0]; 

      if (playing !== true) {
        audio.play();
      } else {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
      }

      playing = !playing
      jQuery(this).siblings().find('audio').each(function(index, elem){
          elem.pause();
          elem.currentTime = 0;
      });
            
  });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player" >
  <h2>Fractions du Silence</h2>
  <audio class="sound">
    <source>
      <a href="http://localhost:8888/sabrinama.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Fractions-du-silence-Bertrand-Dubedout.mp3">Fractions du silence</a>
    </source>
  </audio> 
    </div>
  <div class="player">
  <h2>Merlin, 1. Movement</h2>
  <audio class="sound">
    <source><a href="http://localhost:8888/sabrinama.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Merlin-1.-Movement-Andrew-Thomas.mp3">Merlin, 1. Movement (Andrew Thomas)</a>
    </source>                 
  </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean here "i would like to pause the current one and start another directly." by saying directly, do you mean like pause one audio, go another audio and press play?

Comment: Hi Mosia, what i mean is fist click->play current & pause all other, second click on the same button->pause curerent, click another button-> pause first one, pause all other and play this. At the moment i need two clicks

Comment: in other words... additionally to play current and pause all other, i want  if the first one is playing and i click the second button, the first one should pause and the second should play

Comment: I understand, cool let me check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.player', function() {
  let players = $(document).find('.player');
  $.each(players, function(i, val) {
    if ($(this).data('id') !== $(val).data('id')) {
      if ($(val).data('playing')) {
        $(val).data('playing', false);
        let audio = $(val).find('audio').get(0);
        audio.pause;
        audio.currentTime = 0;
      }
    } else {
      if ($(val).data('playing')) {
        $(val).data('playing', false);
        let audio = $(val).find('audio').get(0);
        audio.pause;
        audio.currentTime = 0;
      } else {
        $(val).data('playing', true);
        let audio = $(val).find('audio').get(0);
        audio.play;
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player" data-playing="false" data-id="1">
  <h2>Fractions du Silence</h2>
  <audio class="sound" preload="auto">
<source src="http://localhost:8888/sabrinama.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Fractions-du-silence-Bertrand-Dubedout.mp3">Fractions du silence</source></audio>
</div>
<div class="player" data-playing="false" data-id="2">
  <h2>Merlin, 1. Movement</h2>
  <audio class="sound" preload="auto">
<source src="http://localhost:8888/sabrinama.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Merlin-1.-Movement-Andrew-Thomas.mp3">Merlin, 1. Movement (Andrew Thomas)</source></audio>
</div>
```

I actually have done this myself, but with video instead of audio. The principle is the same.

```
<div class="player" ><h2>Fractions du Silence</h2>
<audio class="sound">
<source><a href="http://localhost:8888/sabrinama.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Fractions-du-silence-Bertrand-Dubedout.mp3">Fractions du silence</a></source>
</audio> 
</div>
<div class="player">
<h2>Merlin, 1. Movement</h2>
<audio class="sound">
<source><a href="http://localhost:8888/sabrinama.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Merlin-1.-Movement-Andrew-Thomas.mp3">Merlin, 1. Movement (Andrew Thomas)</a></source>                  </audio>
</div>
```

Above is the code you have, underneath here I will write how I did it.

```
<div class="player" data-playing="false" data-id="1">
<h2>Fractions du Silence</h2>
<audio class="sound">
<source src="http://localhost:8888/sabrinama.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Fractions-du-silence-Bertrand-Dubedout.mp3">Fractions du silence</source>
</audio> 
</div>
<div class="player" data-playing="false" data-id="2">
<h2>Merlin, 1. Movement</h2>
<audio class="sound">
<source src="http://localhost:8888/sabrinama.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Merlin-1.-Movement-Andrew-Thomas.mp3">Merlin, 1. Movement (Andrew Thomas)</source>                  </audio>
</div>
```

I have applied data attributes to the html, so these will be seperate entities without relying on a global variable in js and in the js you can see why I did it.

```
var playing = false;

jQuery('.player').click(function() {
  jQuery('.player').removeClass('playing');
    jQuery(this).addClass('playing');

    jQuery('.playing').each(function(){
      var audio = jQuery(this).find('audio')[0]; 

      if (playing !== true) {
        audio.play();
      } else {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
      }

      playing = !playing
      jQuery(this).siblings().find('audio').each(function(index, elem){
          elem.pause();
          elem.currentTime = 0;
      });
            
  });   
});
```

I already wrote down that with data attributes you won't need the global variable playing you have.

```
$(document).on('click', '.player', function(){
let players = $(document).find('.player');
$.each(players, function(i, val){
if($(this).data('id')!== $(val).data('id')){
$(val).data('playing', false);
let audio = $(val).find('audio').get(0);
audio.pause;
audio.currentTime=0;
} else {
$(val).data('playing', true);
let audio = $(val).find('audio').get(0);
audio.play;
}
})
})
```

Like I've done with your html code. I've made some changes to the js. Firstly I completely dropped the jQuery calls you make, these are all replaced with the $ which is the same.

Following this I made the event document on() instead of .player click(). This will make it possible for in the future when you want to add more things dynamically.

After that I collected all the players in a let and with a each loop you can do things with each of them. In this case I check if the data-id is equal to that of the clicked player. If its false, pause it and set time to 0, if true, play the audio.

If you want to you can make an addition within the if that will check if the player is playing by placing you can place the following if and ifelse

```
if($(val).data('playing'))
{
$(val).data('playing', false);
let audio = $(val).find('audio').get(0);
audio.pause;
audio.currentTime=0;
} else {
$(val).data('playing', true);
let audio = $(val).find('audio').get(0);
audio.play;
}
```

This if else can be used when you click the player that is already playing, for the click on a different player after pause you just need the if part.

Edit:
I saw in the html you used an a tag, this is not needed when working with audio and video, its `<source src="location of file">`

Edit2:
I tried with the code snippet on getting it to work, or atleast error free. The sound won't play because of localhost.

Comment: thank you very much. I've tried it, but can't get it to work. At the moment it plays nothing.

Comment: @Benedikt I will update it my answer soon, because I see a little thing I missed before

Comment: @benedikt I gave an update. This time I have it free of errors, but it won't play because there is no music to look for. You will need to test it in your own code.

Comment: thank you again for your time and your ideas. I've tried it as you said, but i can't get it to work.